# Explain why "-" is not a "-"

Tags: python, python-idle

I was writing an automation script in python that dealt with sending commands through a Telnet session. For some reason I couldn't get it to work. After a ton of frustrating debugging, I found that when I was translating a command of:

```
"ulimit -s 1024"
```

The - in the command became something weird in utf-8. I had to translate it in bytes because I was sending it using Telnet (I know I should use ssh, but it honestly is fine in my case) and I realized it was weird because when I printed the command in bytes it would be:

```
b"ulimit \x##\x##\x##s 1024"
```

I don't remember the exact numbers, but I fixed it by copying and pasting a new "-" that I used two lines up in the function and worked fine.

I did copy and paste in the part from two lines up, but I typed the ulimit -s part. I was also using IDLE

Anyone know what happened?

Comment: You need to add some context, how were you running the command?

Comment: You may like the Wikipedia page on [IDN homograph attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack). You probably had a character that looked like a dash but wasn't.

Comment: If it wasn’t a HYPHEN-MINUS (-), then it was something else. And the only way it became that would be that you entered it at some point. It’s impossible for us to tell how it became some other dash character; only you could tell by thinking about what you did.

Comment: It was probably one of these dashes: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm

Comment: Did you by any chance cut and past that command from word-processing software like MS-Word or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone know what happened?

I can see two possibilities here. One is that you inadvertently copy-pasted a line of code from a Web page or other document where the - had been replaced by an emdash (it usually happens to me with quote signs and typographic quote signs), which looks like a minus sign but it's a UTF8 multibyte sequence.

The other is that somehow the IDLE editor effected a "spelling check" like that of Microsoft Word, which replaces (among others) quote signs with typographic quote signs, three consecutive dots with an ellipsis and minus signs with emdashes. This *might* have been triggered by some rare keystroke combination typed in error (for example I sometimes trigger the Windows 7 Screen Magnifier while trying to type in, I think, a { symbol - which on my keyboard is <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>AltGr</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>).

Comment: Idle does word completion but not spell checking.  I believe tab to n spaces (n=4 unless changed in Options) is the only time it changes a character typed by a user.

Answer (score 6):

You managed to enter something like an [U+2013 EN DASH](https://codepoints.net/U+2013) or an [U+2014 EM DASH](https://codepoints.net/U+2013), which both look a lot like the ASCII character [U+002D HYPHEN MINUS](https://codepoints.net/U+002D).

Because either of these characters are outside of the basic Latin-1 alphabet, encoding either one of these to UTF-8 results in a 3-byte sequence:

```
>>> print('\u2013')
–
>>> print('\u2013'.encode('utf8'))
b'\xe2\x80\x93'
>>> print('\u2014')
—
>>> print('\u2014'.encode('utf8'))
b'\xe2\x80\x94'
```

Those two are not the only confusable characters; a few more:

- [U+2010 HYPHEN](https://codepoints.net/U+2010) ‐ (UTF8: E2 80 90)
- [U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN](https://codepoints.net/U+2011) ‑ (UTF8: E2 80 91)
- [U+2012 FIGURE DASH](https://codepoints.net/U+2012) ‒ (UTF8: E2 80 92)
- [U+FE58 SMALL EM DASH](https://codepoints.net/U+FE58) ﹘ (UTF8: EF B9 98)
- [U+FE63 SMALL HYPHEN-MINUS](https://codepoints.net/U+FE63) ﹣ (UTF8: EF B9 A3)

etc.